# In what way should I ask someone about someone's acquaintance with another person?

Tags: present-perfect, questions, present-simple

Are both of them correct and have the same meaning?

**Options:**

> 1. Do you know Tom?
> 2. Have you met Tom?

Comment: They are both correct and mean much the same thing although it might take more than a single introduction before you can be said to *know* someone. The word *know* covers everything from *mere recognition* to *Intimate acquaintance*.

Comment: 1) Do you know Tom?- _at all (have you acquainted with him?)_ 
2) Have you met Tom? (have you seen him recently?) means some significant event has happened that should be told

Comment: @Max -- to me, "Have you met Tom?" means have we ever met him or been introduced to him. "Have you seen Tom?" Means today or recently have you seen him. "Do you know Tom?" Has nothing to do with how well we might know him when asked like this. It means have you been introduced to Tom. "How well do you know Tom?" Speaks to that exactly -- the depth of your relationship.

Comment: @Max, I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and have the same meaning.

- *Do you know Tom?* and *Have you met Tom?* - both refer *to being acquainted with Tom*. Did you ever see this person before? Do you have any idea who he is? Have you ever met before?